# Creating new models on the run Django

Tags: django, models, server

I have a table with words saved in it:
e.g.

```
     WORDS
    "word1"
    "word2"
    "word3"
```

I want to have models that are based off these words, in this example I want to have these models:

```
word1_users
word2_users
word3_users
```

And when I add to table WORDS "word4", I want to have word4_users automatically created. How can I achieve this?

Comment: in which table should ``word2_users`` be? what tables are you talking about?

Comment: It seems like you want to have dynamic models. You can invent your own wheel.

Comment: did you find a way to create models ?